# Supabase realtime slow and skipping some broadcasts

Tags: javascript, supabase

I'm using supabase realtime channels to build a collaborative editor. I'm using slatejs and I'm broadcasting operations on the channel but the broadcasts appear really slow on other clients and also some of the broadcasts are lost.

This is the main code:

```
  const blockUpdateChannel = supabaseClient.channel(
    "block-updates" + DOCUMENT_ID
  );
  // Applying the received broadcasts to current editor
  blockUpdateChannel
    .on("broadcast", { event: "blockupdate" }, (event: any) => {
      

      Editor.withoutNormalizing(editor as any, () => {
        const operations = event.payload.ops;

        operations.forEach((operation: any) => {
          console.log(operation);
          if (operation.source !== userId) {
            editor?.apply(operation);
          }
        });
      });
    })
    .subscribe();

    // sending broadcasts
    const ops: any = [];

    editor?.operations.forEach((operation: any) => {
      var shouldAdd = false;
      if (!operation.source) {
        if (operation.type !== "set_selection") {
          shouldAdd = true;
          if (operation.type === "set_node") {
            if (operation.newProperties.modifiedByUserId !== undefined) {
              shouldAdd = false;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      if (shouldAdd) {
        operation.source = userId;
        ops.push(operation);
      }
    });
    if (ops.length) {
      console.log("Sending ops", ops);
      blockUpdateChannel.send({
        type: "broadcast",
        event: "blockupdate",
        payload: { ops },
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can debug Supabase Realtime by looking at the (new) Realtime logs at:

`https://app.supabase.com/project/YOUR_PROJECT/database/realtime-logs`

You can also inspect the websocket frames with Chrome Inspector. There may be some odd messages there. Or you might find that it's disconnecting / reconnecting frequently for some reason.